# Displaying a message to Internet explorer 8 and Below Users

Tags: internet-explorer-8, filter, standards

So I have been working on a site (http://getcours.tk/), recently, It works fine in Chrome (So webkit) and Firefox (So Gecko) but I just tried it out in Internet explorer 8 and Since it doesn't seem to follow CSS3 standards, It is incapable of rendering it properly.

I just want to display a message to users of internet explorer 8 and below (ie9 works) to say that the site will display incorrectly in their browser, and that if they wish to see it properly they should Use a Modern browser.

Really hoping for a hand here, thanks to anyone who can help

-jman6495

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really simple actually. You can paste this anywhere in your page and everything inside it will only be rendered by IE8 and below

```
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>

    //Whatever you want here

    //For example, specific css only for IE
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssIE.css" />


    <![endif]-->
```

Similarily you can use "gt" (greater than) instead of "lt" or any number version you want.

Comment: Sorry i took so long ;) thanks very much ! (1 year late)