# How to display a message to IE 8 and below whilst not loading and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website only supports IE 9 and above. I want to display a message to the any users using IE 8 or below that they should update their browser. I'm using jQuery along with various other scripts. I'm using jQuery 2.1.1 and obviously that's not supported in IE8, so I used the following conditional statements:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->

<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (!IE)]><!-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<!--<![endif]-->
```

As far as I can see, this has fixed the jquery errors, however I'm now getting errors with other javascript files.

Is there a way I can just tell IE 8 and under not to load any of the js files and display a message? I want to do a creative page with the message, so do I write the html markup within these conditional statements? Do I put these statements in the head or the body of my html file? I know they should really go in the head, but I've seen them placed in the body before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show a hidden element... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964678/displaying-a-message-to-internet-explorer-8-and-below-users or put html in it.

Comment: put a js redirect in a conditional comment pointing to a static page with your message. no jquery required.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `lte` or `gte` where appropriate:

Stuff for IE 8 AND below:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    You're using IE 8 or lower, get a life! :)
<![endif]-->
```

Stuff for IE 9 AND above:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->
```

There is no obligation for you to put these in the `head` only so you can freely use them in the html document everywhere, even for writing up nice messages.

Source: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html